# Imperative to OOP Style - Snippet

Tags: java, oop, object, styles

What is the best way to make this snippet more object oriented?

```
public class Formatter {

    private Service service;

    public Formatter(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String doTheJob(String theInput) {
        String response = service.askForPermission();
        switch (response) {
        case "FAIL":
            return "error";
        case "OK":
            return String.format("%s%s", theInput, theInput);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Object orientation is a technique, not a goal

Comment: @reaanb It could totally be a goal. "How do I apply object orientation to this code" isn't a strange question. This question is, however, too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Why do you need to change your code?  It seems pretty simple, and certainly doesn't need to be "more object oriented".

Comment: @VinceEmigh It shouldn't be a goal if its purpose is unknown. Looking at the actual code, the question doesn't make much sense to me. It's pretty atomic. I don't see how the subject of object orientated modelling even relates to such a short, simple piece of code. Even less unclear is the *why*.

Comment: It's a exam question for my OOP course

Comment: @Vince compare against "what is the best way to make this code more procedural?"  Why would anyone want to?  Too many people believe OOP is all that is good.  Now, if there was a need, e.g. to abstract over different Formatters, I'd be happy to apply OOP techniques.

Comment: If it's an exam question edit your question to include your thoughts and what you have found out before coming here.

Comment: @runDOSrun How about using polymorphism to handle the response rather than a switch? It could still apply. Like I said, his question is opinion based. But it's totally possible to ask how you could make your code more object oriented. No one said he didn't understand the concept of OOP, and not everyone knows all the tricks from the start.

Comment: @reaanb Who cares their reason. Maybe it's a requirement. And it's possible to make it more procedural, just like my OOP example (with the switch statement). Your argument isn't valid. Now, in this case, like I've said before, it's opinion based and isn't fit for SO. But asking how to make code more object oriented isn't some obscure question.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I did indirectly, assuming that it was his own code. As it turns out I was partly right as it was in an exam; it's an artificial question not grounded in a practical scenario (that lacks any context or explanation from the author). Yes, it's a legit question. But with analogies to the XY problem.

Comment: @runDOSrun I already stated the question was off topic. It's a bad question for StackOverflow. That does not mean it's an obscure question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't need to be more complicated, you shouldn't change anything.

But if you write an example of a principle I think it's a good example where to use some "Factory/Delegation" pattern. The principle is to create a class with children class for all your cases. Then you register every cases and use a method to choose what good class to use with your response. With this method you don't have to use a switch/case which is "not very object oriented" for purists.

Your code could be something with the following principle (be careful it's just a code to illustrate the principle):

```java
abstract class Job {
    public abstract String doTheJob(String theInput);
}

class FailJob extends Job {
    public String doTheJob(String theInput) {
        return "error";
    }
}

class OKJob extends Job {
    public String doTheJob(String theInput) {
        return String.format("%s%s", theInput, theInput);
    }
}

class NullJob extends Job {
    public String doTheJob(String theInput) {
        return null;
    }
}


class Formatter {
    private Service service;
    private Map<String, Job> jobs;

    public Formatter(Service service) {
        this.service = service;

        // init the jobs
        jobs = new HashMap<String, Job>();
        jobs.put("FAIL", new FailJob());
        jobs.put("OK", new OKJob());
    }

    public String doTheJob(String theInput) {
        String response = service.askForPermission();
        Job job = getTheJob(response);
        return job.doTheJob(theInput);
    }

    private Job getTheJob(String response) {
        Job job = jobs.get(response);
        if(job == null) {
            job = new NullJob();
        }

        return job;
    }
}
```

But, once again, if your code is all you have to do, stuck with it, it's way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a typical StackOverflow-Answer, since it asks for an "opinion". Consider posting it on **Code Review** for better answers.

Nevertheless: I would suggest these changes.

1. **Do not use a return type for missing permissions**, but treat them using exceptions. This will make your code shorter and more focused on functionality, than on technical aspects like permissions.
2. **Use Superclass `Object` as parameter.** This will make your API more convinient - at no extra costs, since `String.format` execpts Objects as parameters anyways.
3. Last and least: **Use meaningful names**. `Service` does not tell everybody, what this class is made for. Think about refactoring it to `PermissionChecker` or maybe even something more specific. This will help others to understand your code and to find relevant code passages.

The resulting code could look like this:

```
public class Formatter {

    private PermissionChecker permissionChecker;

    public Formatter(PermissionChecker permissionChecker) {
        this.permissionChecker = permissionChecker;
    }

    public String doTheJob(Object theInput) {

        // check permission, fail with exception, if something goes wrong
        permissionChecker.assertFormattingPermission();

        return String.format("%s%s", theInput, theInput);
    }
}
```